# Strip tag from text (in React JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, dom, replace

I have multiple whole html code in variable *cleanHTML* and i need to strip specific tags from text.

```
let cleanHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

this:

```
<span class="remove-me">please</span>
<span class="remove-me">me too</span>
<span class="remove-me">and me</span>
```

to this:

```
please
me too
and me
```

I´m trying to do it with:

```
var list = cleanHTML.getElementsByClassName("remove-me");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i] = list[i].innerHTML;
}
```

But i´m getting error from React *cleanHTML.getElementsByClassName is not a function*

Any idea how to do it in a way React likes?

Comment: `cleanHTML` is just a string? You could theoretically load it with a `xmldoc` parser, and then get the textContent (you don't want any html in your react jsx)

Comment: `>([^>]*)<?` $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing from your specification that your `cleanHTML` is a string, so you would need to convert the string to a node (eg: by creating a div from it), and then parsing the nodes appropriately.

Please note that you really need to request the `textContent` and not the innerHTML, as you do not want to have any html in your react output

```js
const htmlContent = `<span class="remove-me">please</span>
<span class="remove-me">me too</span>
<span class="remove-me">and me</span>`;

const getNodesToRemoveFromElement = (stringContent) => {
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = stringContent;
  return el.getElementsByClassName('remove-me');
};

for (let node of getNodesToRemoveFromElement( htmlContent ) ) {
  console.log( node.textContent );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your `cleanHtml` is a string and not a node. So `getElementsByClassName` does not apply as it is not a string function

You can use regular expressions to do this. Following code might help.

```
var stripedHtml = cleanHtml.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

And `stripedHtml` will have your html content without tags.

Comment: I know that this will stripe all the tags, but i´m trying to stripe out only tags with a specific class