# How to Insert copied text to Textarea without styling?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a problem in my project that is the user copies a text and insert it into a Textarea, the text will be inserted with its style, but If he writes the text himself, the text will be inserted correctly.

How to solve this problem and always insert only the text (even if it is copied)?

the first one is the copied one, the second is the written one

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove html entities from your text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257993/strip-tag-from-text-in-react-js

Comment: I think there is a better way to handle this  (but I don't know how). It's not convenient to go through all the text areas in my project and add HTML entities removal for their values

Comment: What UI library do you use? A custom `textarea` component might support formatting by default.

Comment: "react-contenteditable": "^3.2.6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by stripping the HTML Entities from a string like what is done [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/376/how-to-strip-html-from-a-string-extract-only-text-content-in-javascript)