# How to extract HTML textContent without removing the line breaks <br/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this function to extract the Text from the Textareas in my project (to avoid saving the copied text styling in the database),

```
export const stripHTML = (text) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");

  temporalDivElement.innerHTML = text;
  return temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";
};
```

The problem is that now the user can't write any line breaks in the text. What is the best way to solve that so I get a clean text but with the line breaks?

Comment: insert more code

Comment: What does *"avoid saving the copied text styling"* mean? Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected results

Comment: Is it this answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417527/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-getting-text-from-a-textarea/40426477#:~:text=value.,HTML%20value%20will%20preserve%20newline.

Comment: @charlietfl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153738/how-to-insert-copied-text-to-textarea-without-styling

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365465/extract-text-from-html-while-preserving-block-level-element-newlines

Comment: Depends on how stripped down you need it. Could replace `<br/>` with `\n\r` and then do the text conversion. Will lose automatic breaks from block elements. Another approach is parse all the elements and remove their attributes and save as html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the function in the question `stripHTML` and adding this function as onPaste listener

```
onPaste(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the div, just do this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
temporalDivElement.innerHTML = textarea.value;
var tempText = temporalDivElement.textContent || temporalDivElement.innerText || "";
return tempText.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: I need the div so I can remove the styling from copied elements .. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153738/how-to-insert-copied-text-to-textarea-without-styling